# Bing search for exact phrase containing “@”

Tags: search, search-engine, bing

When I search `"@test"` in Google, the results contain exact `@test` phrase (which is right) but in Bing it ignores `@`. Is there anyway to change Bing's behaviour?

Comment: Why would you use Bing anyway?

Comment: Because there are choices and Google isn't what it used to be http://mvark.blogspot.in/2014/08/big-fat-google.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried it like this on Bing, I was able to see the keyword @test in a lot of the results though not all results - **"[@test]"**